# Using ajax to render content in rails after form submission

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I know this question has been asked several times but I am having following the trouble.

I am creating a simple hangman game, and I have created a keyboard, so there are 26 forms that look like this:

```
            <%= form_for @puzzle, :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'keyq'} do |f|%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :letters_guessed, value: "Q" %>
            <% end %>
```

I store the letters in an array type db field `:letters_guessed`

which I then use to loop to see if the user has guessed the letter.

```
<div class="mystery">
            <% @puzzle.word.length.times do |digit| %>
                <% letter = @puzzle.word[digit] %>
                <% if @puzzle.word[digit] == " " %>
                <br>
                <% elsif @puzzle.letters_guessed.include?(letter.upcase)%>
                    <%= letter %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "_" %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
</div>
```

So essentially, I need to update the mystery div with the new array.  As of now, when I submit the form, nothing happens (to be expected I suppose).

Here is my controller action

```
    def update
      @puzzle.letters_guessed = @puzzle.letters_guessed + [params[:puzzle][:letters_guessed]]
      @puzzle.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
```

The idea here is that I create a new array, and save it.  Now comes the part I'm not sure what to do with the renders.

I've created a _puzzle.js file in the same directory as the other views... How do I get the new array back to my view without actually refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating update.js.erb inside the app/views/YOUR_MODEL/ and simple put alert("Goes here");

It will be a great start.

Comment: I got that showing up thanks!...  what about the call to get the array?

Comment: all instance objects are available in update.js.erb , try alert("<%= @puzzle %>");

Comment: should I create a loop for js and not ruby then?  to see if the player has guessed the letters?

Comment: Okay. It seems that this is your first time.

What I normally do is to separate the view into a partial. Then i render it again.

$("#container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'model/partial_name', object: @object) %>")

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you have already stated in your question, you need to use AJAX to submit the form and then on success callback, you get back the content of *_puzzle.js.erb* file. What you need to do after that is modify your DOM. This is most easiest done with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). jQuery also has nice [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) functionality with which you can do your AJAX requests. Please also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960245/1744702) as it shows you an example of submitting the form.

Good luck!